# My React app only routes to http://localhost:4002/api/v1/... api bakend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I deployed a React and Nodejs API backend on different servers. All the servers work well.
And I also added the BaseUrl Api route in app-route.js like this -

```
export const BaseUrl = "http://ec2-11.192.292.19.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/v1"

export const Auth_Controller_Login = BaseUrl + "/auth/signin"
```

But the problem is when I call a react login page from the browser, it freezes and the browser doesn't respond to anything and then I inspected what was wrong. And the error message shows like that -

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And also the POST Method from React app only routes to the localhost API backend even though I added the correct nodejs backend BaseUrl. The error shows like that -

```
POST http://localhost:4002/api/v1/auth/signin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

As the error on inspect console shows, the react only routes to localhost. What might possibly seem to be a problem?

Comment: maybe your company laptop firewall blocking them

Comment: No bro. I tested on my own laptop.

Comment: try to check is it working on postman

Comment: bor `BaseUrl ` is wrong `http://localhost:4002/api/v1/`

Comment: Sry. You need to read my question properly. I think you don't get it what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

you have to mention full URL like this,
replace this lines,

```
export const BaseUrl = "http://ec2-11.192.292.19.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/v1"

export const Auth_Controller_Login = BaseUrl + "/auth/signin"
```

here still baseUrl is getting wrong, so keep full path,

```
export const Auth_Controller_Login = "http://ec2-11.192.292.19.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/v1/auth/signin"
```

As `BaseUrl` still keep pointing to wrong path of `http://localhost:4002/api/v1/auth/signin`

Comment: still pointing to the wrong BaseUrl.